# How to create a lookup table in python when the dependent parameter value depends on multiple variables

Tags: python, lookup-tables

I have a database like the following, in which the value of the parameter 'b' depends on the values of multiple other parameters, viz. a(1), a(2) ... a(n):

```
a(1),a(2),a(3),...,a(n) : b
```

and multiple lines like this. The value of 'n' is also dynamic and varies across various data sets.

What is the best way to construct a lookup table for this kind of data in Python?

One way could be using a nested dictionary with the values of  **a(i)** as **i-th** level of key, but it seems too cumbersome to create such a dictionary dynamically.

### Additional Information

I need the lookup table to find values of the variable b for different combinations of values of a(1), a(2) ... a(n).In many cases the values of a(i) is a range instead of a specific value. and its not a SQL database.

I basically have to loop through the the value set of various a(i) variables and find the appropriate value of the variable 'b' for that particular value set.

example data set:

```
a(1)    a(2)    b
1-2     1-2    5-15
1-2     3-4    16-30
3-10    1-4    10-30
```

Comment: What are the operations that you'll need to perform on this data structure?

Comment: By database, do you mean like MySQL? because you can always just use an ORM like SQLAlchemy

Comment: Do you want to create some kind of cache or what do you want the lookup table for?

Comment: Having a `dict` with the tuple (a(1),...,a(n)) as key doesn't work well in your case?

Comment: @Bakuriu, OP haven't proposed a dict with such tuples, he proposed a nested dict with key a(i)

Comment: @Tapajit Dey, I think your solution is good, i also would have added some caching mechanism for frequently accessed mapping

Comment: @Michael Exactly. Mine was a suggestion for a different solution. since `flat is better than nested` using a tuple as key is generally better than having nested dicts.

Comment: @Bakuriu, not always it is a better solution, specially for the range query the OP has mentioned, searching by integer primitive in this case will be better.

Comment: @Michael When I posted that comment the OP did not say anything about ranges(or actually what he wanted to do) and thus I *had* to propose a solution which work well generally.