# dynamically nesting a python dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to create a function that will create dynamic levels of nesting in a python dictionary.
e.g. if I call my function **nesting**, I want the outputs like the following:

```
nesting(1)  :  dict = {key1:<value>}
nesting(2)  :  dict = {key1:{key2:<value>}}
nesting(3)  :  dict = {key1:{key2:{key3:<value>}}}
```

and so on. I have all the keys and values before calling this function, but not before I start executing the code.

I have the keys stored in a variable **'m'** where m is obtained from:

```
m=re.match(pattern,string)
```

the pattern is constructed dynamically for this case.

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve? This seems a bit convoluted.

Comment: have you considered recursion?

Comment: @Greg, recursion in Python should be avoided if possible :) Seems like the keys (captured groups?) are stored in a plain list, so they can be traversed with a simple loop.

Comment: I need this to implement the method as explained in : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14725594/how-to-create-a-lookup-table-in-python-when-the-dependent-parameter-value-depend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate over the keys like this:

```
def nesting(level):
    ret = 'value'
    for l in range(level, 0, -1):
        ret = {'key%d' % l: ret}
    return ret
```

Replace the `range(...)` fragment with the code which yields the keys in the desired order. So, if we assume that the keys are the captured groups, you should change the function as follows:

```
def nesting(match): # `match' is a match object like your `m' variable
    ret = 'value'
    for key in match.groups():
        ret = {key: ret}
    return ret
```

Or use `reversed(match.groups())` if you want to get the keys in the opposite order.

Comment: It's not create dictoinary with multiple.It create always single key value dictionary

Answer (score 1):

```
def nesting(level, l=None):
    # assuming `m` is accessible in the function
    if l is None:
        l = level
    if level == 1:
        return {m[l-level]: 'some_value'}
    return {m[l-level]: nesting(level-1, l)
```

For reasonable `level`s, this won't exceed the recursion depth. This is also assuming that the value is always the same and that `m` is of the form:

```
['key1', 'key2', ...]
```

An iterative form of this function can be written as such:

```
def nesting(level):
    # also assuming `m` is accessible within the function
    d = 'some_value'
    l = level
    while level > 0:
        d = {m[l-level]: d}
        level -= 1
    return d
```

Or:

```
def nesting(level):
    # also assuming `m` is accessible within the function
    d = 'some_value'
    for l in range(level, 0, -1):  # or xrange in Python 2
        d = {m[l-level]: d}
    return d
```